# Jquery mobile - Return to index after a button click event

Tags: javascript, function, jquery-mobile, button, redirect

I am new to the Jquery Mobile technology and I must admit there are some little things in the behavior of this framework that I do not understand yet. I am developing a tablet application using Cordova 2.9.1 and JQuery Mobile 1.2.0 (my version of the regular JQuery is 1.8.2).

Basically, I have a multi-pages html file (2 pages). On the two of them, I use a dumb form and a dumb button to validate the inputs.

**HTML code - `index.html`**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>               
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="index">
        <div data-role="content">
            <form name="login_form">
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
                    <br/>
                    <button data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" class="connection_button">Se connecter</button>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <a class="force-reload" href="#mdp_oublie" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" data-transition="slide">Mot de passe oublié</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="mdp_oublie">
        <div data-role="content">
            <form name="email_form">
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
                    <button data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" class="email_button" onclick="email_recovering(this)">Valider</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I had some issues to trigger the button click event. After a few researches, I have come to use this kind of method in my index.js file.

**Javascript code - `index.js`**

```
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function ()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.connection_button', function (e)
    {
        if(e.handled !== true)
        {
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            if(username == "a" && password == "b")
                alert("OK");
            else
                alert("KO");

            e.handled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that when the "Se Connecter "button is clicked, the function is executed the way it should, but JQuery then redirects me to the index page (the first one). I do not understand why...

My two questions are :

1. Is the way I call my connection_button function a good one ? I tried several times the $(document).ready() {}); method and it does not work for me. Do you have any better ?
2. Do you have any idea about the redirection to index page when the function has been called ?

I hope that I have been as clear as possible.
Thank you.

Comment: You should use id and not class to identify this button, unless you plan to have many... I would use <button onclick=your_function()> and only have your_function in the js code if I were you. You do not need more than this to handle a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right think to do for buttons (at least for jQuery Mobile 1.2.0) is to use `<a href="#">` links:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" id="connection_button">Se connecter</a>
```

in this way there is no redirection to other pages. I have fixed your JavaScript and created a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74hdJ/)** with your code:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "[data-role=page]", function(event, ui)
{
    $(document).on("click", "#connection_button", function(event)
    {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        if(username == "a" && password == "b")
            alert("OK");
        else
            alert("KO");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#email_button", function(event)
    { 
        email_recovering(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for these explanations. I applied them and the problem was the same.

After some research, I finally found what should be the solution : 

It seems that PhoneGap crashes on iOS since the 2.7.0 version, returning the error **CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1** when you try to navigate to an anchor on the same page. More info here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3530

The code you uploaded in JSFiddle is OK and runs well, but when I tried it in my project I had this PhoneGap error.

Anyway, thank you, your advices are great.